# Remote access, configuration and monitoring needs for linux machines in retail venues (shops) distributed across the country.

Tags: linux, puppet, salt, newrelic, mcollective

We plan on deploying machines with a Linux distro, in retail venues (shops) across the country. The venues have their own connectivity with the wider world and their own network, which we have no control over. We also need an ability to configure Chrome in these machines. The machines are simple desktops, which we will set up and distribute in venues, and they have the following ongoing needs…

- Remote monitoring – we have New Relic for all our EC2 servers, and a strategy to use New Relic would work well as the team is already familiar with it. Is that feasible?
- Remote configuration and upgrade – again puppet and mcollective are the tools of choice as they would probably do the job and the team is well aware of the toolset.
- Chrome configuration – will something like Google Admin Console work to configure the browser.

Comment: Hey Prabin, what exactly are you looking for, or what is your question?